# UITableViewCell not appearing/reusing correctly from NIB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

I have created a custom UITableViewCell from a NIB. Everything appears when the rowHeight is not set (albeit, everything is squished). I am not sure if I am reusing and creating the cells properly:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"ARCell";
    ARObject *myARObject;
    myARObject = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ARCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = arCell;
        self.arCell = nil;
    }

    UILabel *label;
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:0];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myARObject.username];

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myARObject.created_at];

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myARObject.articleTitle];

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myARObject.intro_text];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   CGFloat rowHeight = 105;
    return rowHeight;
}
```

Problems:

1. Not all labels appear when rowHeight is set. If rowHeight isn't set, labels are squished
2. When rowHeight is not set, selecting an item shows all of the labels

Answer (score 0):

Remove the else clause

Answer (score 0):

You call loadNibNamed, but don't store result anywhere! Can't understand why your code works at all... Anyway, writing blind I would try something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"ARCell";
    ARObject *myARObject = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ARCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }

    UILabel *label;
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:0];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myARObject.username];

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myARObject.created_at];

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myARObject.articleTitle];

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myARObject.intro_text];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 105.0;
}
```

Comment: i get the same result. instead of cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0]; I am assigning it to arCell which is a UITableViewCell property in my h file

Comment: I am following the example in the Apple TableView Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1

Comment: Checked and the sample looks like your code. Then just check your arCell IBOutlet "because of the outlet connection you made, the tvCell outlet now has a reference to the cell loaded from the nib file."

Comment: Just to check: is the problem with cell reuse or size? You can verify reuse with NSLog(@"") calls, but resizing reused cells is something totally different. Your code uses hardcoded value 105, which I thought is correct value for all cells?